# A question on the duty to procreate

Tags: pru-urvu

Bet Hillel ruled that a man fulfills his obligation to procreate when he has a boy and a girl.  The Sages say:  If a man’s children die while he is alive, he has not yet fulfilled his obligation to procreate, unless the dead children themselves left a boy and a girl among them. [Yevamot 62a; Shulchan Arukh, Even HaEzer 1:6]

What if the man had only one child (not two), and this child dies, leaving a boy and a girl.  Has the man fulfilled his obligation?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.1.6?lang=he&with=all